# jquery mobile local storage & autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I have this webapp, which I'm creating with JQuery Mobile. On Page 9 the user can store his personal data and on page 4 the data can be retrieved in a html form. So this works fine. However, on page nine I have the field PLZ (Zip Code), Gemeinde (City) and Kanton (State). After entering PLZ the city and state are populated automatically. This worked fine before, but when I pasted in this webapp code, it doesn't work. I tried it also on Page 4, where normal the data are retrieved only and there the auto populate works. I cannot find the error. Can you help me?

I know there are some problems with the paths, e.g. under Phonegap in the head. This doesn't matter, because I normaly works with phonegap on local pc. This is just a copy on a testsserver to work online.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>IVZ Schweiz GmbH</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="ivz.png" >
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="ivz.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    <!--PhoneGap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

<!-- Icon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/Icon.png" >
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/ajax-loader.gif" >

<!--JQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
var ac_config = { 
source: "plz.php", 
select: function(event, ui){
$("#plz").val(ui.item.plz);
$("#gemeinde").val(ui.item.gemeinde); 
$("#kanton").val(ui.item.kanton); 


}, 

minLength:1 
}; 

$("#plz").autocomplete(ac_config); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>

<body>

                <!-- Personaldaten -->
            <div data-role="page" id="p4">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

        <a href="#p2" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">zurück</a>
            <center>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo2.png" >
            </center>
        <a href="#p5" data-icon="arrow-r" data-transition="slide">weiter</a>    

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <h1>
            Personalien
            </h1>
       <form name="signup-form">
                <label for="name">Vornamen:</label>
                <input type="text" name="vornamen" id="vornamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">Nachnamen:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nachnamen" id="nachnamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">Adresse:</label>
                <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="plz">PLZ</label>
                <input type="text" name="plz" id="plz" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="gemeinde">Ort</label>
                <input type="text" name="gemeinde" id="gemeinde" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="kanton">Kanton</label>
                <input type="text" name="kanton" id="kanton" value="" />                
                <br>
                <label for="name">Geburtsdatum</label>
                <input type="date" name="geburtsdatum" id="geburtsdatum" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
                </form>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').FormCache();
});
</script>
</div>
        </div>

        </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#p1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p9" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slideup">Meine Daten</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p7" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slideup">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--End Page 4-->




        <!-- Meine Daten -->
            <div data-role="page" id="p9">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

        <a href="#p2" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">zurück</a>
            <center>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo2.png" >
            </center>
        <a href="#p5" data-icon="arrow-r" data-transition="slide">weiter</a>    

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <h1>
            Meine Daten
            </h1>
               <form name="signup-form">
                <label for="name">Vornamen:</label>
                <input type="text" name="vornamen" id="vornamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">Nachnamen:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nachnamen" id="nachnamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">Adresse:</label>
                <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="plz">PLZ</label>
                <input type="text" name="plz" id="plz" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="gemeinde">Ort</label>
                <input type="text" name="gemeinde" id="gemeinde" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="kanton">Kanton</label>
                <input type="text" name="kanton" id="kanton" value="" />                
                <br>
                <label for="name">Geburtsdatum</label>
                <input type="date" name="geburtsdatum" id="geburtsdatum" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="name">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="speichern" />
                </form>
            </div>
<script>
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.FormCache = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
        }, options );

        function on_change(event) {
            var input = $(event.target);
            var key = input.parents('form:first').attr('name');
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);

            if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                data[input.attr('name')] = input.is(':checked');
            }else {
                data[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
            }

            localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(data);
        }

        return this.each(function() {    
            var element = $(this);

            if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                var key = element.attr('name');

                var data = false;
                if(localStorage[key]) {
                    data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
                }

                if(!data) {
                    localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify({});
                    data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
                }
                element.find('input, select').change(on_change);

                element.find('input, select').each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('type') != 'submit') {
                        var input = $(this);
                        var value = data[input.attr('name')];
                        if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                            if(value) {
                                input.attr('checked', input.is(':checked'));
                            } else {
                                input.removeAttr('checked');
                            }
                        } else {
                            input.val(value);
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
            else {
                alert('local storage is not available');
            }
        });
    };     
}( jQuery ))
</script>

        </div>


        </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#p1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p9" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slideup">Meine Daten</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p7" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="slideup">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--End Page 9-->





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the browsers console. Do you see any errors. Some versions of JQM especially new ones dont play well with Jquery UI. JQM V2 will include Jquery UI. So your code may be ok but its not running because of prior errors with those frameworks. plus you are loading Jquery 1.11 and 1.4. any reason why you are loading different versions of the same jquery

Comment: I cannot see any error. I tested yesterday in phonegap too. And there I have the same issue. I think I have to give the form an ID, what do you think?

Comment: im not sure if an id would help but try